# How to dynamically change html tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Is this possible in angularjs/jquery/javascript?

```
<div ng-init="font='h2'">
  <h1> h1 is this size </h1>
  <{{font}}> this is a {{font}}</{{font}}>
</div>
```

How to dynamically change html tags?

ps: I already tried this code, but with no success.

Comment: It's certainly possible. What exactly do you need to change

Comment: He means change the tag from a `<span>` to an `<a>`, for example.

Comment: You can always use jQuery to create a new element using the new tag, set its .innerHTML, then replace the old element with the new one. Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/j5077qjn/ (hint: jQuery is JavaScript)

Comment: @ChrisG Or, you know, normal Javascript.

Comment: Depending on what you need to do you might be better off changing the class vs the html tag.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I want  font = h2 or h5. Then I can change it dynamically.

Comment: Please find Demo https://jsfiddle.net/pk5a2n2r/1/ using jQuery & jQuery Template

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a custom directive:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.font = 'h2';
  $timeout(function() {
    $scope.font = 'h3';
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.font = 'h4';
      $timeout(function() {
        $scope.font = 'h5';
      }, 1000);
    }, 1000);
  }, 1000);
}]);

app.directive('font', function($interpolate, $compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: false,
    link: function($scope, $element, $attr) {
      var content = $element.html();
      $scope.$watch('font', function(newVal) {
        $element.contents().remove();
        var tag = $interpolate('<{{font}}>{{content}}</{{font}}>')
          ({
            font: $scope.font,
            content: content
          });
        var e = angular.element(tag);
        $element.append($compile(e)($scope));
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-init="font='h2'" ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyController">
  <h1> h1 is this size </h1>
  <font>This is a {{font}}</font>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as jQuery you could use the [replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) method. You'd just need to preserve the text/class during the click event.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.button').on('click', function() {
    var $span = $('.span');
    var lvl = $(this).data('lvl');
    
    $span.replaceWith(`<${lvl} class="span">${$span.text()} as an ${lvl}<${lvl}>`);  
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="button" data-lvl="h2">Change to h2</button>
<button class="button" data-lvl="h5">Change to h5</button>

<div ng-init="font='h2'">
  <h1>h1 is this size </h1>
  <span class="span">this is a font</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a plain Javascript solution:

```js
var i=0;
setInterval(function()
{
  document.getElementById("changeable").outerHTML = "<h" + (i+1) + " id=\"changeable\">" + document.getElementById("changeable").innerHTML + "</h" + (i+1) + ">";
  i++;
  if(i>=5){
    i=0;
  }
},1000);
```

```html
<div>
  <h1> h1 is this size </h1>
  <h2 id="changeable"> this is a header tag</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Certainly possible with both JavaScript and JQuery.

JavaScript: use document.getElementById("MyId").outerHTML

JQuery: See this for reference - http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/#selector

This may seem like a bad practice to modify DOM elements through JavaScript (although possible)

If using Angular, I would recommend using ng-if or a combination of ng-if and ng-include if you would want to conditionally load up a new view/html